# How to send data from EditText from one fragment to an TextView in an other fragment while both are in the same Fragment Drawer? Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, mobile

As the title says, I want to capture the user name with a Edit Text in one fragment and display it on a TextView on the second fragment.

I am reading a lot of different info about it, but I am not being able to make sense out of it, even less making it work.

It is for a college project, the goal is to make a fragment drawer like it was a service app.
Also, I know almost nothing of Java, hence my struggle.

Could someone teach me how to do it?
Thanks in advance. :D

```
package com.example.devmobile.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.devmobile.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        return root;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.devmobile.ui.catalogo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.devmobile.databinding.FragmentCatalogoBinding;
import com.example.devmobile.ui.home.HomeViewModel;

public class CatalogoFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentCatalogoBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel catalogoViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentCatalogoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textCatalogo;
        catalogoViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.devmobile;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<String> selectedItem = new MutableLiveData<String>();
    public void selectItem(String item) {
        selectedItem.setValue(item);
    }
    public LiveData<String> getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use viewModel whom scope is activity.

ViewModelProvider:

```kotlin
constructor(
    private val store: ViewModelStore,
    private val factory: Factory,
    private val defaultCreationExtras: CreationExtras = CreationExtras.Empty,
)
```

actually, the constructor you used is(first one)

```kotlin
public constructor(
    owner: ViewModelStoreOwner
) : this(owner.viewModelStore, defaultFactory(owner), defaultCreationExtras(owner))

public constructor(owner: ViewModelStoreOwner, factory: Factory) : this(
    owner.viewModelStore,
    factory,
    defaultCreationExtras(owner)
)
```

**Fragment** and **Activity** both is `ViewModelStoreOwner`. So

```kotlin
HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
```

**homeViewModel** store in activity, other fragment whom parent is your activity could access it.

or you just use prompt, like "use ViewModel in fragment, store in activity" in ChatGpt.

Comment: Ok so... I'm a noob at it, what is the difference between that and a shared viewlmodel? 
And how I do that exactly. 
Also, thank you for answering. :D